# Set array in while use outside while

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I created a script where I set a array in an existing array through a while loop from a SQL database.

```
while ($nextday = odbc_fetch_array($nextdayinfo)){
$username = $nextday['user_sign'];
  if(isset($username)){
  $nextday[] = array('value' => $username, 'text' => $username);
  }
}
```

This is the code. If I try to `print_r($nextday)` after the IF clause, it will show me all the information, as soon as i put the `print_r($nextday)` after the while clause, it stops working.

Comment: What is `$nextday`? Array? Or result returned from `_fetch`?

Comment: $nextday is an empty array. I want to create it in the while clausule.

Comment: But your array has the same name as the database row, so it is overwritten on every iteration.

Comment: @Jerodev CCCCCCCombo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same variable for the fetched database row as your array. So the array is overwritten by the new row at every iteration.

Try defining your array outside of the loop and using a different name.

```
$array = [];
while ($nextday = odbc_fetch_array($nextdayinfo)) {
    $username = $nextday['user_sign'];
    if (isset($username)) {
        $array[] = [
            'value' => $username, 
            'text' => $username
        ];
    }
}

print_r($array);
```